# Ruby on Rails - Active Record - Relationships - Many to Many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## Short Version:

This works when I team.tournaments but not when I do tournaments.teams.  It gives me:

```
  <main>'irb(main):117:0> tournament.teams << team
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."tournament_id" = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: teams.tournament_id: SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams"  WHERE "teams"."tournament_id" = 1
```

## Long Version:

I want to have a relationship between a team and a tournament that is a many to many relationship.  I understand I have to do this through a join table which is done in the first portion shown below.  From there, I have to add the association as shown in the team / tournament models respectively.

```
    class TeamTournamentJoinAttempt3 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :teams_tournaments, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer "tournament_id"
        t.integer "team_id"
    end
    add_index :teams_tournaments, ["tournament_id", "team_id"]
  end

  def down
    drop_table :teams_tournaments
  end
end
```

Tournament Model:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end
```

Teams Model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tournaments
end
```

Now I can do locate a team and a tournament in the rails console using:

```
tournament = Tournaments.find(1)
team = Teams.find(1)
```

Then I can create a relationship between the two using:

```
team.tournaments << tournament
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "teams_tournaments" ("team_id", "tournament_id") VALUES (1, 1)
    (123.1ms)  commit transaction
```

And boom, I think everything is working.  However when I try to go the other way (`tournament.teams << team`) it doesn't work giving me the following error:

```
tournament.teams << team
    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    (0.0ms)  commit transaction
    Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."tournament_id" = 1
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: teams.tournament_id: SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams"  WHERE "teams"."tournament_id" = 1
```

Comment: Interesting. I copied your migration and your models and it worked fine for me. I was able to shovel either way (a tournament onto team.tournaments or a team onto tournament.teams). What do your tournament and team migrations look like?

Comment: I just did a hard reset, cleared everything, replaced all my migrations and it worked.  I have no idea what was wrong before.  However I greatly appreciate your help.  I'm not sure how to mark answer since it worked originally however if anyone reads this, the above code is a decent sample of how to make a many to many and then how to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing `TeamTournamentJoinAttempt3` my bet is on not using `reload!` in Ruby console after experimenting with `belongs_to` or `has_one` association.